# SQL: How to select a max record each day?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

[image]

I found a lot of similar questions but no one fits perfectly for my case and I am struggling for hours for a solution. My table is composed by the fields DAY, HOUR, EVENT1, EVENT2, EVENT3. Therefore I have 24 rows each day. EVENT1, EVENT2, EVENT3 have some values and I'd like to select each day only the row (I mean the record) for which EVENT3 has the maximum value in the day (among the 24 hours). The final outcome will be one row per day

[image: source table]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql) are all potential duplicates. Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: day hour Event1 Event2 Event3
1/10/2020 17 5916278 237923 7475239
1/11/2020 17 5927063 241140 7498775

Comment: If two hours in the same day have the same event3 value, which one would you want to choose? Would you like to see both in those instances?

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.event3 = (select max(t2.event3)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.date = t.date
                 );
```

In most databases, this has very good performance with an index on `(date, event3)`.

A more canonical solution uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date order by event3 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option aside from using correlated subqueries is to write this is a left self-join, something like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
LEFT JOIN t AS t2 ON t.day = t2.day AND t2.event3 > t.event3
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

If you want to select an arbitrary matching row each day in the event of multiple rows with the same maximum event3, tack `GROUP BY t.day` on the end of that.

I'm not sure how performance of this is going to compare to Gordon Linoff's solutions, but they might get assembled into quite similar query plans by the RDBMS anyway.